# Send domain entity as paremeter or send entity id as parameter in application services

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

when using domain driven design, is it better that your services' methods receive an entity as parameter or the id of your entity as parameter so that you can retrieve the entity inside the method using a repository?

for example:

```
public void Apply(Job job, User user)
```

versus

```
public void Apply(int jobId, int userId)
```

Comment: It is the `user` that applies for the `job`, right? How about `user.Apply(job)`. I know, what about the app services? I had a discussion with a Java crowd and they slapped me around big time on this. DDD is not about forgetting about OOP. Yes it is the `user` that applies for the `job`.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/ndddsample

Comment: @ryudice It certainly would be testable.

Comment: @MikeEast While your OO suggestion is good advice the question is a little more abstract - specifically about how the parameters should be formed. agreed?

Comment: @ryudice Would the question be clearer worded: "How to encapsulate a domain entity as a method parameter? id integer or entity instance?"

Answer (score 9):

DDD is about mapping your client's vocabulary to your design. Your client (hopefully) talks about users applying for jobs, not some integer ID being linked to another integer ID. Try to **stick to the real world** as close as possible, unless it becomes a burden.

By passing in the entire entity, you can benefit from the entity's behavior immediately, without having to construct it first.

So stick to entities, unless you have a situation where you *often* only have an ID to work with. This usually happens when you're dealing with **external systems**, such as web services. In that case you can create a method overload that accepts the ID. This overload should validate the ID, construct the entity and call the overload that accepts the entity.

```
public void Apply(int jobId, int userId)
{
    // Validate the IDs.

    // Construct the entities.
    var job = ...;
    var user = ...;

    // Call the 'proper' overload.
    Apply(job, user);
}

public void Apply(Job job, User user)
{
    // Actual business logic belongs here.
}
```

Again: try to avoid such overloads as much as possible, unless you're dealing with external systems that only return the ID.

From a coding point of view, entities are also better than integers. An integer can be of any integer value, so you'd have to validate it everywhere you use it. Your factories are responsible for constructing valid entities and your (domain) logic should keep your entities in a valid state. So using the entity is completely safe and shouldn't require much validation.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on ***where*** your **Application Service** resides:

If your Service executes within the **same AppDomain** (i.e. you're calling it from the same executable), then passing the object is ideal.  The Service can easily access other objects within the object graph.

If your Service executes in a **different AppDomain** (e.g. behind a WebService or other remote location), you should use an ID.  The Service would then load the appropriate object from the persistence store before working with it.

If you try to send objects down the wire, you likely run into the [problems described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636277/how-to-solve-state-stateless-in-a-client-server-application).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you send the object, you are creating dependency between the service and the entity. One of the advantages of using services is to act as facades to reduce dependency graph between classes and reduce the complexity of the design. It's better to use primitive types, structs, enums in service contracts but when dealing with large number of method parameters you may encapsulate them in an object but in this case it will be a DTO not an entity.

Comment: What if he was passing in an interface?  Say: Apply(IJob, IUser) ?

Comment: @Adrian K Same advantages as i explained in my answer- they're types so it's better than primitives. The decision to use a contract instead of a concrete would be dependant on your design/architecture. This is not really relevant to the question about how to encapsulate model objects as parameters.

Comment: @Adrian interfaces shouldn't define structure but behavior.

Comment: @cottsak: I am writing my comments here because it's the only place allowed :).. Entities by definition must have an ID. Objects without IDs are immutable value type objects like Money, Address,... . Services occur in the model where is the need to construct a barrier to hide things behind and are meant to be used by outsiders to get information about what's inside. It does not make difference if the service is used for business logic or to interface with other systems. This is only a matter of scale or granularity.

Comment: @cottask If outside entities have reference to the entities behind the service you will get interdependencies everywhere. If you are going to change a class you will have to review, modify, compile and test everything.

Comment: @M.Sameer I'm unsure that we are talking about the same type of "service". If so, this is likely causing confusion in this question.

Comment: To add to this answer, I agree that service contract should accept primitives, enums, structs, and DTOs - no entities. This allows your service method to define a clear business transactional scope within which your entites may be resolved and cached for use within that scope.

Answer (score 1):

I use ViewModel for passing "flat entities" to/from application service. Also I use Document Message pattern to communicate with application service. In application service a use extension methods for business entities something like this:

```
public BusinessEntityViewModel ConvertToViewModel(this BusinessEntity businessEntity)
{
      BusinessEntityViewModel bevm = new BusinessEntityViewModel{ Id = businessEntity.Id, ...}
      return bevm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, difference is only the fact what does Domain do with User and Job to make "Apply" operation. If ID is quite enough, then it is ok to leave there only ID.